# Reflecting an slice of maps, each map is of type struct?

Tags: dictionary, go, struct

I'm trying to iterate through the `interface` `dialogCommands` that is a `slice`. I can iterate through it normally, and the `Println` into each `Index` gives me a `map`. However, this `map` is being printed as having type `struct`

```
    if reflect.TypeOf(dialogCommands).Kind() == reflect.Slice {
    commands := reflect.ValueOf(dialogCommands)

    for i:=0; i<commands.Len(); i++ {
        v := commands.Index(i)
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind())
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
```

The output from this is

```
struct
map[options:[a b c]]
struct
map[startDialogs:[dialog1]]
```

As you can see, the type is a `struct` but the output is a `map`. How to iterate through the `keys` of `v`? I cannot just treat this a map because it's of type `reflect.Value`, so I need a way to iterate through it, but as you see, the `kind` is `struct` while the `Println` says it's a `map`

Update:

Here's the `Dialog` structure

```
type Dialog struct {
    Dialog bson.Raw `json:"dialog" bson:"dialog"`
}
```

and remember that `dialogCommands` gets unmarshaled into `interface{}`

```
[map[options:[a b c]] map[startDialogs:[dialog1]]]
```

Comment: You should include the definition of dialogCommands and whatever is stored in it, not just describe it to us. Best of all is a complete Go program that will run in the Go playground at https://play.golang.org/

Comment: @ZanLynx I updated with better information, do you think it's enough?

Comment: Well it isn't enough to make me interested in poking at it. I'd have to write all kinds of support code and I already have a job. Maybe you'll have luck with someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind()` returns the kind of `v`, not of the underlying value in `v`. The variable v has type [`reflect.Value`](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value). This is a struct type.

The following print statements will print what you expect assuming that `dialogCommands` is a slice of maps:

```
    fmt.Println(v.Kind())  // prints the kind of v's underlying value
    fmt.Println(v)         // prints v's underlying value
```

Based on your comment on this question, it looks like `dialogCommands` is a slice of interfaces. If so, then you will want to work with the interface's element:

```
    if v.Kind() == reflect.Interface {
        v = v.Elem()
    }
    fmt.Println(v.Kind())  
    fmt.Println(v)
```

Comment: Thanks, it prints in the place of 'struct'. But how is this possible if when printed, it says it's a map?

Comment: I mean, it prints 'interface' as the kind, opposed to 'struct' of before

Comment: See the updated answer. What is the type of `dialogCommands`?